# How do I make negative signs appear on the left of numbers in a right to left box in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, right-to-left

I'm developing a calculator in C# and I ran into a stumbling block. As usual calculators do, I have my text box set to RightToLeft. However, when I convert the number to a negative number using my + - button, the negative sign always goes to the RIGHT of the number, not the left. How do I make it appear on the left side using a right to left box?

My negative converter:

```
decimal neg;
neg = number * 2;
number = number - neg;
richTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(number);
```

Comment: Windows Forms, or WPF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> As usual calculators do, I have my text box set to RightToLeft.

No, that’s not what usual calculators do. Set `TextAlign` instead. (And use a regular `TextBox`, not a `RichTextBox`. `RichTextBox`es are hard to format, but you can select the entire thing and use `SelectionAlignment` if you really need to.)

Comment: (This one is Windows Forms.)

Answer (score 2):

Right-to-left mode is used for certain languages such as Arabic, where people read and write starting from the right side of the page. So having the minus sign appear to the right is natural.

For your case, you want to set the alignment of the text instead.

```
richTextBox1.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx

Comment: @minitech huh.. didn't think of WinForms vs. WPF! I guess we have both answers out there now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be modifying the incorrect property on your richTextBox.
The code you want to use is this.

```
richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
richTextBox1.SelectedText = Convert.ToString(number);
```

Comment: Does `TextAlignment` exist?

Comment: no (my bad) it doesn't - have corrected my answer, but it appears I've been beaten to it.